# Disabling weekends and Previous days from JQuery datepicker

Tags: jquery, html

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $.datepicker.setDefaults({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});
        $("#datepicker1").datepicker({ beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends });
        $( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker({ minDate: 0});
        $( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker();                   
    });
</script>
```

i have the above code to which i want to disable weekends and previous dates from my JQuery datepicker.. But what it does is that it only disables weekends and not the past days. Where have i went wrong???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass all settings to a single call

```
$(function () {
    $.datepicker.setDefaults({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
    });
    $("#datepicker1").datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
        minDate: 0
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this

```
$(function() {
    var date = new Date();
    var currentMonth = date.getMonth();
    var currentDate = date.getDate();
    var currentYear = date.getFullYear();
   $('#txtDate').datepicker({ 
       minDate: new Date(currentYear, currentMonth, currentDate),  // will disable past days
       beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends // Will disable weekends
   });
});
```

### [**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rLnTQ/876/)

*Docs*

[**minDate**](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate)

[**beforeShowDay**](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay)

Answer (score 1):

**fiddle:**

**http://jsfiddle.net/rLnTQ/877/**

you can use all options in one shot instead of doing it seperately. 
you are calling the datepicker many times, which is not needed.

```
$(function() {
   $.datepicker.setDefaults({
   // here we can have all the common properties which we need for all the datepickers
       dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
       duration:"slow"
   });

   $('#datepicker1').datepicker({ 
       minDate:0,
       dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', // this is for single datepicker.
       beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you are re-initialising the datepicker each time you specify a option to it ,  to achieve both the requirement, do it this way

**JQUERY CODE:**

```
              $("#datepicker1").datepicker({
                  minDate: 0,
                  beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends
              });
```

**LIVE DEMO:**
http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/XsG27/3/

Happy Coding:)

Comment: this is already answered..if you have something different you can post it

Comment: @susheel: I actually prefer this answer to yours (and all the others), as he actually explains what the problem is, rather than simply specifying the solution.

Comment: cool down guys why do you downvote for each and everything. i just said it is similar answer. even I gave an explaination inshort. i didn't downvote your answer though

Comment: @susheel: my name is Dreamweiver, that was just a status quote :)